# Impala: duplicate table alias when trying joining on multiple columns

Tags: sql, join, hive, impala

I want to left outer join table A and table B on multiple columns. Below is my code:

```
select * from table_A

    left outer join table_B
     on (table_A.a1 = table_B.b1)

    left outer join table_B 
     on (table_A.a2 = table_B.b2)
```

But then I got error:

```
HiveServer2Error: AnalysisException: Duplicate table alias: 'table_B'
```

Does anyone know whatI did wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different table aliases as you are joining the same table twice.

```
select *  -- use column names here instead of *
from table_A ta
left outer join table_B tb1 on (ta.a1 = tb1.b1)
left outer join table_B tb2 on (ta.a2 = tb2.b2)
```